# What is the difference between System.IO.File and System.IO.FileInfo?

Tags: c#

Why are there two classes for almost the same purpose `System.IO.File` and `System.IO.FileInfo` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) provides static members related to working with files, whereas [`System.IO.FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) represents a specific file and contains non-static members for working with that file.

From MSDN:

> Because all File methods are static,
>   it might be more efficient to use a
>   File method rather than a
>   corresponding FileInfo instance method
>   if you want to perform only one
>   action. All File methods require the
>   path to the file that you are
>   manipulating.
>
> The static methods of the File class
>   perform security checks on all
>   methods. If you are going to reuse an
>   object several times, consider using
>   the corresponding instance method of
>   FileInfo instead, because the security
>   check will not always be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

In general they do two very *different* things:

- `System.IO.File` - getting/working with *any* file
- `System.IO.FileInfo` - getting/working with (including metadata) *a particular* file

Granted they do share a few methods with the same purpose, but for the most part they have very different purposes/scenarios that they serve best.